# What will be a smoother transition into GNOME for Ubuntu 18.04-- Ubuntu GNOME or Vanilla Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome

^^^^
Will Ubuntu GNOME upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, or will support discontinue when 18.04 is released?? Just want to know what's better to run right now so I can upgrade and not have to reinstall later(I intend to see this transition through)-- GNOME installed correctly on vanilla Ubuntu, or Ubuntu GNOME?

Comment: We can guess from what we see. The next version of standard Ubuntu, 'Artful Aardvark' to become 17.10 in October is already using the gnome desktop environment and at the same time there is also an Ubuntu Gnome flavour.  You can download (or better `zsync`) the daily iso files via the iso testing tracker, http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/376/builds

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather just stick to LTS releases because they give people longer to identify/fix bugs on certain systems.

Comment: It is a good idea to stick to LTS releases for your main operating system (and maybe test the 'latest and greatest' operating systems separately).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both merging into one package-set by the sounds of it... So whatever you're most comfortable with now would be my answer.

Even were that not the case, switching desktop environments isn't hard. Certainly nothing that would stop me using what *I* considered to be the best choice for the next few months.

From the [Ubuntu Gnome blog post on this](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/):

> Next year, if you are using either Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS, you will be prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. For normal release users, this upgrade should happen with the release of 17.10.